# Calculate image size and position for Parallax scrolling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, size, parallax

I’m stuck and this is already making me crazy! I need your help for some parallax scrolling calculations.

In **[the working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ujrwLpwn/)** the image inside the container moves slower than it’s container with a speed of -0.5.

Now I need the image to move faster than the container with the value of +0.5. But it’s not working! I’ve tried some many possibilities but I guess I’m not a math pro. — In the middle of the screen all should be centered!

So how do I get the correct position of the image when it moves faster inside the container?

Full code in the **[DEMO!](https://jsfiddle.net/ujrwLpwn/)**

Extract:

```
var $cont = $(this),
    contOffsetTop   = $cont.offset().top,
    img             = $cont.find(parallaxBackground),
    speed           = img.attr("data-parallax-speed"),
    contHeight      = $cont.height(),
    imgHeight       = (windowHeight * Math.abs(speed)) + contHeight,
    imgOffset       = imgHeight - contHeight;

var scrollDist      = windowHeight - contOffsetTop - contHeight / 2,
    posY            = scrollDist * -speed - imgOffset;

img.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(-50%, ' + posY + 'px, 0)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(-50%, ' + posY + 'px, 0)',
                  'top': '0'
});
```

Pleeease – and thanks in advance!

Comment: :Is this issue resolved for you?

Comment: Not yet, still improving my math skills ...